# Where to handle PDF creation in a Django React site

Tags: django, reactjs, pdf, django-rest-framework

I have a site that uses Django REST framework for the backend, react for the frontend, and axios to handle requests between them.

I want my site to be able to create PDFs for the users. I looked on the web and found that I can create PDFs through both Django and React. I am wondering which one I should use to handle the PDF creation.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to handle pdf creation on server side, As for server side you know that system you are using on the server is a powerful system as of you don't know what system your clients will be using also if there is any mobile app develops through that api pdf generated from server side will be compatible else you need to generate pdf for mobile app.
In django you can use xhtmltopdf, wkhtmltopdf to generate pdfs from an html template.